# Can Hibernate filters be used with criteria queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, filter, hibernate-mapping

The Hibernate documentation gives some information on [Hibernate filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters), and talks about HQL and load fetching in that section.  But it never explicitly mentions anything about using them in conjunction with [criteria queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objecstate-querying-criteria).  Would something like the following be expected to work?  Assume Hibernate 4.3.

Entity definition

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="myFilter", parameters=@ParamDef( name="myParam", type="integer" ) )
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="myFilter", condition="myField = :myParam")
} )
// assume MyType contains some mapped field named "myField"
public class MyType { ... }
```

Query code

```
sess.enableFilter("myFilter").setParameter("myParam", 1);
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(MyType.class);
//set some other restrictions on crit
List items = crit.list();
```

Will items have had `myFilter` applied?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to add the "JPA" tag.  I just sorta clicked it from "Related tags".

Comment: Did you try it? What was the outcome?

Comment: I tried, and it didn't work.  Our code is a bit complicated (far more than my snippet above), and has been ported forward over many different major Hibernate versions, so it's hard to tease out theoretically expected vs observed behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work for Criteria too. The filters are applied on the Session level, no matter what you use to load the entities (e.g., HQL, entityManager.find(), Criteria API).

Comment: Where can I find working example for filter applied native queries?

Comment: You don't need a Filter for native queries. You have the WHERE clause for that.

Comment: You have Native Queries inside parentheses, above. That's why I asked.

Comment: That was for CRUD-level native queries via the `@Loader` annotation.